# Rails: form with :url specified can't be used as partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm trying to use a form as a partial for both the new/edit views of my `albums` controller/model. However, it's giving me the error when I try to edit the album:

`No route matches [PUT] "/users/22/albums"`

I think this might have to do with my form's `:url`. My form works fine when I submit it to create an album, but gets that error when I try to edit it.

I tried taking out the `url: user_albums_path` in my form, but it would just give me an error when I try to create a new album.

`No route matches [POST] "/albums"`

Is there any way to make it so that the form works for both actions? I feel like the :url can't coexist properly in both actions.

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for (@album), url: user_albums_path, :html => { :id => "uploadform", :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<div class="formholder">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>


    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>

    <br>

    <%=f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

albums controller

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController

def index
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @albums = @user.albums.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @albums }
  end
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @album.update_attributes(params[:album])
      format.html { redirect_to user_album_path(@user, @album), notice: 'Album successfully updated' }
    else
      format.html { render 'edit' }
    end
  end
end

def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.find(params[:id])
end

def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.build(params[:album])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to user_album_path(@user, @album), notice: 'Album was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @album, status: :created, location: @album}
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end 
end

def new
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = Album.new
end

def destroy
end
```

end

please help!

update:

FIXED IT! on my own! the form just needed to be `<%= form_for([@user, @album])...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<%= form_for [@user, @album] %> 
# other arguments can be inserted before the closing brace
```

That syntax properly scopes the resource routes

Remember to have an `@album` instance variable if you need one. You can build an empty album using `@user.album.build`

Comment: yeh I eventually figured it out on my own! that was the correct answer though!